# How to make a function return two columns of different types (R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, function, cbind

So I have a function that applies simple arithmetic to three columns of numeric data of a dataframe (TypeChart) and binds it to the row names of the dataframe:

```
TypeCombo <- function(type1, type2, type3) {
  cbind(row.names(TypeChart), TypeChart[,type1] * TypeChart[,type2] * TypeChart[,type3])
}
```

This does successfully multiply the three columns together, but returns them as a character vector instead of a numeric one. Is there something I can change within this function to return a list/dataframe with the first column being characters and the second being numeric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cbind` doesn't return a data.frame but a matrix. Try this instead:

```r
TypeCombo <- function(type1, type2, type3) {
  data.frame(names = row.names(TypeChart),
             values = TypeChart[,type1] * TypeChart[,type2] * TypeChart[,type3])
}
```